# AbstractMap's containsValue() method implementation

Tags: java, dictionary

`containsValue()` is implemented in `AbstractMap` class as below:

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    if (value==null) {
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            if (e.getValue()==null)
                return true;
        }
    } else {
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
            if (value.equals(e.getValue()))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

What if the implementation had been as below:

```
public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    Iterator<Entry<K,V>> i = entrySet().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Entry<K,V> e = i.next();
        if (e.getValue().equals(value))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there any performance improvement by implementing a null specific checking in the original method?

Comment: Java  Map support null as value as well key. So `e.getValue().equals(value)` could be `e.null.equals(value)`, simply null pointer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your suggested implementation, `e.getValue().equals(value)` would throw a `NullPointerException` if `e.getValue()` is null, which is why you must have separate logic to handle null.

It's not a matter of performance. It's a matter of correctness.

Comment: Ohh I forget Map accept null as key/value. Had it been a problem if map wouldn't be accepting nulls?

Comment: @PravatPanda Had the Map not accepted null values, it would make more sense to start the method with `if (value==null) return false;`, since there would be no point in iterating over all the entries of the map in this case.